# printing a hash into an output file after creating it on the command line

Tags: perl, output, hash

I am trying to use a hash that was created and extracting the results into a output file. My script is down below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

#### sample of `first_file` data

```
>nameID ABCD
```

#### sample of `second_file` data

```
>nameID 0.5
```

#### My Perl code

```
my ( $first_file, $second_file ) = @ARGV;

my %name;

{
    open my $fh, '<', $first_file or die qq{Unable to open "$first_file": $!};

    my $key;
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        if ( /^>(\S+)/ ) {
            $key = $1;
        }
        elsif ( /\S/ ) {
            chomp;
            $name{$key} .= $_;
        }
    }
}

open my $fh, '<', $second_file or die qq{Unable to open "$second_file": $!};
while ( <$fh> ) {
    if ( /^>(\S+)/ ) {
        printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $name{$1} // 'undef';
    }
}
```

The trouble I was having was extracting `printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $name{$1} // 'undef'` from the command line into an output file.

Comment: i attempted to use the following format and i was not having much success

         unless (open(OUTPUT, "$output_file") ) {
         print "cannot create new file \"$output_file";
         }
         while(my $line = <
         print OUTPUT ""%s\t%s\n", $1, $name{$1} // 'undef'";}

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the `printf` line to print? Please give an example. It's difficult to tell by how you've laid things out.

Comment: printf line prints the number and letters if the the number is present in the second file

so say that 1, 2, and 4 are present in the second file. then 1, 2, and 4 will be printed along with their corresponding letters

Comment: That code is mostly my solution to [this question](stackoverflow.com/questions/31008421) but the data you say you've got now is different. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes i generalized it. i thought it would be simpler to explain.

Comment: But there are commas in the input now whereas there weren't any before, and there's a space after the `>` that wasn't there, and the ID is now a number. You need a different program to handle that

Comment: I know, I used those as separation makers. I'll edit them if they are causing any confusion.

Comment: Are they really there in the data file? If not then you should really remove them from your question. Better still show some real data

Comment: Thanks. And is there really a space after the `>`? FASTA files don't normally look like that

Comment: Thanks! I've tidied your Perl code a little and added some markdown so that it's clear where the data starts and ends. Hope that's okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to redirect the output to a file is to specify it on the command line

```
program.pl file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

I suggest you do it that way so that you can choose where the output gets sent without editing the program

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I've changed your regexes a little bit. Note that I've assumed your lines start with a ">" character, and the "--" you used in your example aren't there (otherwise, your regex will need to start with `/^-->`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ( $first_file, $second_file ) = @ARGV;
my $write_file = 'output.txt';

my %name;

open my $fh1, '<', $first_file
  or die qq{Unable to open "$first_file": $!};

while ( <$fh1> ) {
    s/,//;
    if ( /^>\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/ ) {
        $name{$1} = $2;
    }
}
close $fh1;

open my $fh2, '<', $second_file
  or die qq{Unable to open "$second_file": $!};

open my $wfh, '>', $write_file
  or die "Unable to open write file $write_file: $!";

while ( <$fh2> ) {
    s/,//;
    if ( /^>\s+(\S+)/ ) {
        printf $wfh "%s\t%s\n", $1, $name{$1} // 'undef';
    }
}

close $fh2;
close $wfh;
```

Input file 1:

```
> 1, ABCD
> 2, XFSD
> 3, GDWE
> 4, MMDD
```

Input file 2:

```
> 1, 0.5
> 4, 9.99
> 6, 22.22
```

Output file:

```
1   ABCD
4   MMDD
6   undef
```